# is_page_template returning false

Tags: page-template, child-theme

I'm using woothemes Canvas with a child theme. Additionally, I am using the WP Listings plugin. I am creating a custom listings page template (overriding the plugin template) and I'm having issues recognizing the page type to include scripts/styles on that page type only.

Example:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'single-listing.php' ) ) {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name');
    function your_function_name() {
```

the if statement is returning false, although it is using that file.

Comment: Hey Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop is_page_template() will not work. In order to use it after The Loop you must call wp_reset_query() after The Loop. Please use  wp_reset_query() if is_page_template call within the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is how your function is constructed and not your condition as such.

You should not be wrapping your function and your action in a condition like this. Page templates are selected really late in the query by the main query, and I probably think that this is way to late for your action to execute. By the time the condition hits true, the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook already executed and cannot be rerun

If this is a single page, and that single page is for a custom post type called `listing`, you should be using `is_singular( 'listing' )` instead of `is_page_template()`

The correct way would be to wrap your scripts and styles inside your function inside your condition

You can try the following

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name' );
function your_function_name() {
    if( is_singular( 'listing' ) {

        // add your scripts and styles

    }
}
```